# D3.js exit transition: delay has no effectD3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 BubbleChart where I am trying to get the exit selection of the text in the bubbles to delay removal with the following code; but the delay seems to have no effect...
The visualization form the below code behaves identical to it with the delay( 1 ) removed; changing the time parameter to delay anything else does not change the behavior either.

All other transitions in my Bubblechart work as expected.

Any ideas how I could get the delay working?  Thanks!

```
// ... Exit data [from existing g elements], transitioning to 0-radius
  gDataJoin.exit().selectAll( "text" ).transition().delay( 1 ).remove();
  gDataJoin.exit().selectAll( "circle" ).transition().duration( transitionTime ).attr( "r", 0 );
  gDataJoin.exit().transition().delay( transitionTime ).remove();
```

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/0ynu7ej7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay(1)` is the same as `delay` 1 millisecond. So it's working -- for a millisecond.

Change to:

```
gDataJoin.exit().selectAll( "text" ).transition().delay( 1000 ).remove();
  gDataJoin.exit().selectAll( "circle" ).transition().duration( transitionTime ).attr( "r", 0 );
  gDataJoin.exit().transition().delay( transitionTime ).remove();
```

Comment: Yeah that does work, thanks.  Weird, I could have sworn I experimented with different length time parameters like I said in my question and they didn't work then.  I must be doing something different since then...